# Android UI design based on screen resolution

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm looking to make an Android app that changes the look of the UI based on the device it's shown on (4 inch phone, 7inch tablet and 10inch tablet). I know you have the fragments API and it's probably that which I should use for this, but all the examples I've seen just have 2 activities sitting side by side and the code is a bit OTT for my needs (they have events passing between them etc).

Here is the comparison between a 4 inch device and a 7 inch device and how the different UI elements should move around (also note that element A can change design between the two devices).

Any ideas on how I would go about doing this, or if anyone has any sample code that would be fantastic!

[image: Different screen layouts]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should probably design different xml for each size. You can use the qualifier in the layout dir for different screen size. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources

Answer (score 2):

You can use different directory for different size :

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

and for more information :

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Good Luck,,, :D

Answer (score 0):

See also [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) for Android 3.0+.

Comment: I'd already mentioned the Fragments API in the question and was asking how it could be used for my needs..